# How to create Quora like URLs with UTF-8 support?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing an application and I need to allow UTF-8 characters in URL. My application uses PHP (Laravel) and the inbuilt `Str::slug()` function converts the non-English characters to their equivalent English letters.

What I'm looking at is creating URLs like:

```
some-domain.com/अंतरिक्ष-यान-आकाश-में-बादल.1
```

I want one function which I can use to create all the URLs for my site. Can someone suggest how to achieve this?

My existing attempt is this -

```
protected function make_slug($string) {
        return preg_replace('/\s+/u', '-', trim($string));
    }
```

This does the job; but then it fails when the `$string` is something like `You cannot`say`\\\ we\ did it# right!` - basically a bad user input.

Answer (score 0):

PHP regex has some cool selectors like `\p{L}` (letters in all languages) and `\p{N}` numbers (also in all languages), see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Why not use a NOT group (`[^]`) , like:

```
return preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/u', '-', trim($string));
```

So instead of searching for white space with `\s`, you search and replace everything that is not a Letter or Number.

Comment: This isn't working. phpStorm says "Illegal, unsupported escape sequence". The sample url in the question actually gets stripped out.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't read the manual close enough; the actual Regex sequence is `\p{L}` and `\p{N}`. @TheBigK

Comment: It produces ""अ-तर-क-ष-य-न-आक-श-म-ब-दल", which is not what I'm looking for. Any other way to fix this?